# How to run different versions of OpenSSL

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, qt

The upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 broke the Qt 6.x compatibility with OpenSSL (it requires 1.x but there are 3.x installed).
I solved the issue following [this](https://linuxpip.org/install-openssl-linux/) procedure. Now I can run the network functions of my Qt application.
However this workaround broke the gstreamer compatibilty:

```
GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:50:46.632: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.0' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4)
```

Actually `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3` exists, but I'm afraid the procedure linked make OpenSSL 1.0 the default one.

Anyway the messages are a bit confusing, because it says it does not find the version 3 but it actually finds it:

```
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.0' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff561f6000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f8114b1c000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f81146da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f81144b2000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f81141c2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8114be1000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f81141a6000)
```

**How to maintain both so the applications can use what they need?**